# Change The Values That PyInvoice Use

Tags: python, python-3.x, export, receipt

I am wanting to use PyInvoice, it seems to do everything I want, although want to call it a receipt instead, how would this be possible? I would also like to change the values of the column headings, how would I go about doing this?

https://github.com/CiCiApp/PyInvoice

EDIT:

I have managed edit some of it, but cannot seem to move all the "Service Provider" heading over to the left, any ideas on how this can be achieved?

[This is what I want to happen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9d8XT.png)

Thanks Again

Comment: And seems you'd be able to rename the columns here: https://github.com/CiCiApp/PyInvoice/blob/master/pyinvoice/templates.py#L213, and in other similar parts of the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to caution you that I have not used this package but I remember the first time I wanted to modify a library to suit my needs better.  It seemed intimidating but it is not that hard.

I looked at the code and I think I see where you need to make the change

[image: Code from PyInvoice]

This is in line 17 of **/pyinvoice/templates.py**

Comment: Thanks for the help, I have never modified a library before so will give it a go!

Comment: Hello, I have updated the question with an issue I have encountered, was wondering if you have any ideas? Thanks

Comment: @testaccount12321 I noted that I have not worked with this before but I did scan the code and it looks like you have to sort out how from reportlab.lib.enums import TA_CENTER, TA_RIGHT works I would guess there is a TA_LEFT and so you might try to import that and then replace TA_RIGHT with TA_LEFT to see what happens.  I want to also note that if you found my answer useful to mark-it-up